# Proof a function is convex if and only if it meets this condition?

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

How to proof that a function f:R->R is convex if and only if dom(f) is convex and for each a, b, c in it's domain that are $a<b<c$, we have:

Determinant of matrix:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
 1 &     1  &     1\\
  a &     b  &    c\\
 f(a) & f(b)  &f(c)
\end{vmatrix}\ge 0.
$$

Determinant is:

$$    bf(c)-cf(b)+cf(a)-af(c)+af(b)‐bf(a) >= 0$$

Then:

$$   f(a)(c-b) + f(b)(a-c) + f(c)(b-a) >=0$$

Then according to the a<b<c, we can say:

$$    f(a)(c-b) + f(c)(b-a) >= f(b)(c-a)$$ [edited]

So I went until here but I don't know how to connect this to the Jensen's inequality to prove that f is convex.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{c - b}{c - a}$ and $\frac{b - a}{c - a}$ are non-negative and sum to $1$.

Comment: Please use LaTeX

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3240682/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need almost no more steps to go beyond there. The definition of convexity of a function includes the following:
$$
f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y)\le \theta f(x)+(1-\theta)f(y)
$$
Now, try to rearrange the last inequality you obtained with $x=a$, $y=c$ and a proper choice of $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks, my main problem is with f( t x + (1-t) y ). If I choose t= (c-b/c-a), then the right side of the Jensen's inequality is reached, but the left side still remains...like I have f(b)(a-c/c-a) = -f(b) in the left. And I still don't know how to convert this to f( t a + (1-t) c).

Comment: You're welcome. A slight mistake in your answer is $$f(a)(c-b) + f(b)(a-c) + f(c)(b-a) >=0\implies f(a)(c-b) +f(c)(b-a) \ge f(b)(a-c) $$while it should be$$f(a)(c-b) +f(c)(b-a) \ge f(b)(c-a)$$

Comment: Oh, thank you !

Comment: Good luck.${}{}{}{}$